# Org-mode library of babel: can't #'CALL what I define

Tags: clojure, org-mode

I want to use the library of babel of org-mode to define a new Clojure function that would be accessible to any org-mode document.

What I did is to define that new function in a named codeblock like this:

```
#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure
  (defn foofn
    []
    (println "foo test")) 
#+END_SRC
```

Then I saved that into my library of bable using `C-c C-v i`, then I selected the org file to save in the library and everything looked fine.

Then in another org file I wanted to call that block such that it becomes defined in that other context. So I used the following syntax:

```
#+CALL: foo
```

However when I execute that org file I am getting the following error:

```
Reference `nil' not found in this buffer
```

Which tell me that it can't find that named block.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Also once it works, is there a way to add new parameters to that code block when called using `#+CALL:`?

Finally, where is supposed to be located my library of babel? (how to know if it got properly added or not?)

I am obviously missing some core information that I can't find in the worg documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#+CALL: foo()
```

Also, check the value of the variable `org-babel-library-of-babel` to make sure that the C-c C-v i worked properly.